# Another Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call Stack size Conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked at the previous Q&As on this topic, but I am perhaps, just not seeing the error...

Basically, I have a form, with a button at the bottom with this event handler...

(The whole setup is a JS/JQuery/Bootstrap interface running on Chrome to node.js/express.js server linked to MySQL, but those factors don't seem relevant here. )

```
    //create 
$('#createform').on('click', '.create', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var userid = $("#user_id1").val();
  var job_title = $("#job_title").val();
  var description = $("#description").val();
  var requirement = $("#requirement").val();
  var location = $("#location").val();
  var company_id = $("#company_id1").val()
  var oontact_id = $("#contact_id").val()
  var resume_id = $("#resume_id").val()
  var status = $("#status").val()
  var notes = $("#notes").val();
  var rating = $("#rating").val()
  console.log("create job button pushed [", userid, "] [", job_title, "] [", company_id, "] [", status, "] ");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/job",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id1: userid,
      job_title: job_title,
      description: description,
      requirement: requirement,
      location: location,
      company_id: company_id,
      contact_id: contact_id,
      resume_id: resume_id,
      status: status,
      notes: notes,
      rating: rating
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      //location.reload(); // force reload to see new entry
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log("Error ")
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

There was no error with the form in the console. Upon hitting "create" button (which calls this section of code), I get the console log "create job button pushed ..." and the right input, confirming variables were populated. Then the browser froze, and no call was passed to the server.

Browser error stack shows

> "Uncaught RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded at Dt (jquery 3.5.0.min.js:2)" 
>   repeated ad infinitum

And this is confirmed by Chrome's own profiler (under inspection/performance)

I've check this section of code multiple times. A VERY similar code (different table, different fields) ran fine without incident yesterday, but my attempt at making this code/this table is failing miserably. I thought it was location.reload, but it never got that far. The failure is within jQuery, and I honestly don't see where I messed up.

I've checked the typical, like passing val()... (I passed variables read from val(), never directly).

I've tried with or without the preventDefault, but it's not there.

It's SOMETHING within that Ajax call, but what?

Comment: I changed jQuery minified to regular jQuery, and it says the error is in BuildParams

> buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );

So it's calling itself to resolve, but I'm just passing regular vars? Huh?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It's really obscure.

Turns out, jQuery got confused when I named several things the same. This was one of my input fields:

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="job_title" 
             id="job_title" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="job title" required="required">
          </div>
```

As you noticed above, I have a variable named the same.

```
 var job_title = $("#job_title").val();
```

and fed into the ajax data bit.

```
   data: {
      user_id1: userid,
      job_title: job_title,
...
```

Somehow, when the code looks like this, jQuery got very confused trying to de-reference the name vs the ID vs. the field vs. the rest. That is what caused the stack exhaustion.

Somehow, when there are only 3-4 fields this wasn't a problem. But when you have like 10+ fields on a form, it had to iterate through each multiple times, and the stack space got exhausted.

This was resolved by 1) removing the "name" attribute from the Form fields (didn't need them with "id" already set) and 2) de-conflicting the variables.  As long as the ajax gets the right key names and value names it doesn't really care the data get in there.

Your particular solution will vary, but this, at least, was how I solved this problem.

Comment: NOTE: One way to help debug this problem is to use the FULL version of jQuery rather than the minified version. 

If yours choked out in like line 3800's with jQuery 3.5.0, you may have done something like I did, used the same name with NAME and ID. 

The "forget to use val()" Error has the same line number, but has a different error now.